# Hide and Show Element in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with the function to show and hide an element in Laravel. I don't know how to make it like when I click on the "Publish" button, it will hide the post. Furthermore, I want when I click on the "Title", it will lead me to go to the page which displays the full content of that post

This is the demonstrate

[image]

resources\views\livewire\posts.blade.php

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ $post->id }}</td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ $post->title }}</td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">{{ $post->body }}</td>
                    <td class="border px-4 py-2">
                        <button wire:click="publish({{ $post->id }})" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Publish</button>
                        <button wire:click="edit({{ $post->id }})" class="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Edit</button>
                        <button wire:click="delete({{ $post->id }})" class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

app\Http\Livewire\Posts.php

```
public function publish($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
    $this->post_id = $id;
    $this->title = $post->title;
    $this->body = $post->body;
    $this->openModal();
}
```

Comment: @BeefBoodle So, you want to show non-published posts only?

Comment: I want the user when they click on the title of the post, they will go to the new page which displays the full content of the post. If the user clicks on the button 'Publish', it will hide the post